# Sagemaker AlgorithmError: ExecuteUserScriptError:

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker, object-detection-api

I am starting a training job with a custom framework where i provide the source_dir and entry point parameters. The training job fails because the algorithm is unable to find the entry point file, even though it is present in the source_dir. below is the code:

```
    def __init__(
        self,
        entry_point,
        source_dir=None,
        hyperparameters=None,
        distributions=None,
        **kwargs
    ):
        super(CustomFramework, self).__init__(
            entry_point, source_dir, hyperparameters, **kwargs
        )
    
    def _configure_distribution(self, distributions):
        return
    
    def create_model(
        self,
        model_server_workers=None,
        role=None,
        vpc_config_override=None,
        entry_point=None,
        source_dir=None,
        dependencies=None,
        image_name=None,
        **kwargs
    ):
        return None
```

```
from sagemaker.debugger import TensorBoardOutputConfig

hyperparameters = {
    "model_dir":"/opt/training",        
    "pipeline_config_path": "pipeline.config",
    "num_train_steps": 1000,    
    "sample_1_of_n_eval_examples": 1
}

tensorboard_output_config = TensorBoardOutputConfig(
    s3_output_path=tensorboard_s3_prefix,
    container_local_output_path='/opt/training/'
)

estimator = CustomFramework(image_uri=container,
                            role=role,
                            entry_point='run_training.sh',
                            source_dir='source_dir/',
                            instance_count=1,
                            instance_type='ml.m5.2xlarge',
                            hyperparameters=hyperparameters,
                            tensorboard_output_config=tensorboard_output_config,
                            base_job_name='tf2-licence-detection')
```

This is the content of my source dir
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

this is the error message

```
2022-01-24 12:48:29 Starting - Starting the training job...
2022-01-24 12:48:52 Starting - Launching requested ML instancesProfilerReport-1643028520: InProgress
......
2022-01-24 12:50:12 Starting - Preparing the instances for training......
2022-01-24 12:51:13 Downloading - Downloading input data......
2022-01-24 12:52:33 Training - Downloading the training image............
2022-01-24 12:55:01 Uploading - Uploading generated training model
2022-01-24 12:55:01 Failed - Training job failed
2022-01-24 12:54:53,723 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     No GPUs detected (normal if no gpus installed)
2022-01-24 12:54:56,754 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     No GPUs detected (normal if no gpus installed)
2022-01-24 12:54:56,765 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     No GPUs detected (normal if no gpus installed)
2022-01-24 12:54:56,774 sagemaker-training-toolkit INFO     Invoking user script
Training Env:
{
    "additional_framework_parameters": {},
    "channel_input_dirs": {
        "test": "/opt/ml/input/data/test",
        "train": "/opt/ml/input/data/train"
    },
    "current_host": "algo-1",
    "framework_module": null,
    "hosts": [
        "algo-1"
    ],
    "hyperparameters": {
        "pipeline_config_path": "pipeline.config",
        "num_train_steps": 1000,
        "model_dir": "/opt/training",
        "sample_1_of_n_eval_examples": 1
    },
    "input_config_dir": "/opt/ml/input/config",
    "input_data_config": {
        "test": {
            "TrainingInputMode": "File",
            "S3DistributionType": "FullyReplicated",
            "RecordWrapperType": "None"
        },
        "train": {
            "TrainingInputMode": "File",
            "S3DistributionType": "FullyReplicated",
            "RecordWrapperType": "None"
        }
    },
    "input_dir": "/opt/ml/input",
    "is_master": true,
    "job_name": "tf2-licence-detection-2022-01-24-12-48-36-604",
    "log_level": 20,
    "master_hostname": "algo-1",
    "model_dir": "/opt/ml/model",
    "module_dir": "s3://sagemaker-us-east-1-920101086824/tf2-licence-detection-2022-01-24-12-48-36-604/source/sourcedir.tar.gz",
    "module_name": "run_training.sh",
    "network_interface_name": "eth0",
    "num_cpus": 8,
    "num_gpus": 0,
    "output_data_dir": "/opt/ml/output/data",
    "output_dir": "/opt/ml/output",
    "output_intermediate_dir": "/opt/ml/output/intermediate",
    "resource_config": {
        "current_host": "algo-1",
        "hosts": [
            "algo-1"
        ],
        "network_interface_name": "eth0"
    },
    "user_entry_point": "run_training.sh"
}
Environment variables:
SM_HOSTS=["algo-1"]
SM_NETWORK_INTERFACE_NAME=eth0
SM_HPS={"model_dir":"/opt/training","num_train_steps":1000,"pipeline_config_path":"pipeline.config","sample_1_of_n_eval_examples":1}
SM_USER_ENTRY_POINT=run_training.sh
SM_FRAMEWORK_PARAMS={}
SM_RESOURCE_CONFIG={"current_host":"algo-1","hosts":["algo-1"],"network_interface_name":"eth0"}
SM_INPUT_DATA_CONFIG={"test":{"RecordWrapperType":"None","S3DistributionType":"FullyReplicated","TrainingInputMode":"File"},"train":{"RecordWrapperType":"None","S3DistributionType":"FullyReplicated","TrainingInputMode":"File"}}
SM_OUTPUT_DATA_DIR=/opt/ml/output/data
SM_CHANNELS=["test","train"]
SM_CURRENT_HOST=algo-1
SM_MODULE_NAME=run_training.sh
SM_LOG_LEVEL=20
SM_FRAMEWORK_MODULE=
SM_INPUT_DIR=/opt/ml/input
SM_INPUT_CONFIG_DIR=/opt/ml/input/config
SM_OUTPUT_DIR=/opt/ml/output
SM_NUM_CPUS=8
SM_NUM_GPUS=0
SM_MODEL_DIR=/opt/ml/model
SM_MODULE_DIR=s3://sagemaker-us-east-1-920101086824/tf2-licence-detection-2022-01-24-12-48-36-604/source/sourcedir.tar.gz
SM_TRAINING_ENV={"additional_framework_parameters":{},"channel_input_dirs":{"test":"/opt/ml/input/data/test","train":"/opt/ml/input/data/train"},"current_host":"algo-1","framework_module":null,"hosts":["algo-1"],"hyperparameters":{"model_dir":"/opt/training","num_train_steps":1000,"pipeline_config_path":"pipeline.config","sample_1_of_n_eval_examples":1},"input_config_dir":"/opt/ml/input/config","input_data_config":{"test":{"RecordWrapperType":"None","S3DistributionType":"FullyReplicated","TrainingInputMode":"File"},"train":{"RecordWrapperType":"None","S3DistributionType":"FullyReplicated","TrainingInputMode":"File"}},"input_dir":"/opt/ml/input","is_master":true,"job_name":"tf2-licence-detection-2022-01-24-12-48-36-604","log_level":20,"master_hostname":"algo-1","model_dir":"/opt/ml/model","module_dir":"s3://sagemaker-us-east-1-920101086824/tf2-licence-detection-2022-01-24-12-48-36-604/source/sourcedir.tar.gz","module_name":"run_training.sh","network_interface_name":"eth0","num_cpus":8,"num_gpus":0,"output_data_dir":"/opt/ml/output/data","output_dir":"/opt/ml/output","output_intermediate_dir":"/opt/ml/output/intermediate","resource_config":{"current_host":"algo-1","hosts":["algo-1"],"network_interface_name":"eth0"},"user_entry_point":"run_training.sh"}
SM_USER_ARGS=["--model_dir","/opt/training","--num_train_steps","1000","--pipeline_config_path","pipeline.config","--sample_1_of_n_eval_examples","1"]
SM_OUTPUT_INTERMEDIATE_DIR=/opt/ml/output/intermediate
SM_CHANNEL_TEST=/opt/ml/input/data/test
SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN=/opt/ml/input/data/train
SM_HP_PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH=pipeline.config
SM_HP_NUM_TRAIN_STEPS=1000
SM_HP_MODEL_DIR=/opt/training
SM_HP_SAMPLE_1_OF_N_EVAL_EXAMPLES=1
PYTHONPATH=/opt/ml/code:/usr/local/bin:/usr/lib/python36.zip:/usr/lib/python3.6:/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload:/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Invoking script with the following command:
/bin/sh -c ./run_training.sh --model_dir /opt/training --num_train_steps 1000 --pipeline_config_path pipeline.config --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples 1
/bin/sh: 1: ./run_training.sh: not found
2022-01-24 12:54:56,777 sagemaker-training-toolkit ERROR    ExecuteUserScriptError:
Command "/bin/sh -c ./run_training.sh --model_dir /opt/training --num_train_steps 1000 --pipeline_config_path pipeline.config --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples 1"

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnexpectedStatusException                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14188/1459479382.py in <module>
----> 1 estimator.fit(inputs)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sagemaker\estimator.py in fit(self, inputs, wait, logs, job_name, experiment_config)
    690         self.jobs.append(self.latest_training_job)
    691         if wait:
--> 692             self.latest_training_job.wait(logs=logs)
    693 
    694     def _compilation_job_name(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sagemaker\estimator.py in wait(self, logs)
   1665         # If logs are requested, call logs_for_jobs.
   1666         if logs != "None":
-> 1667             self.sagemaker_session.logs_for_job(self.job_name, wait=True, log_type=logs)
   1668         else:
   1669             self.sagemaker_session.wait_for_job(self.job_name)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sagemaker\session.py in logs_for_job(self, job_name, wait, poll, log_type)
   3783 
   3784         if wait:
-> 3785             self._check_job_status(job_name, description, "TrainingJobStatus")
   3786             if dot:
   3787                 print()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sagemaker\session.py in _check_job_status(self, job, desc, status_key_name)
   3336             reason = desc.get("FailureReason", "(No reason provided)")
   3337             job_type = status_key_name.replace("JobStatus", " job")
-> 3338             raise exceptions.UnexpectedStatusException(
   3339                 message="Error for {job_type} {job_name}: {status}. Reason: {reason}".format(
   3340                     job_type=job_type, job_name=job, status=status, reason=reason

UnexpectedStatusException: Error for Training job tf2-licence-detection-2022-01-24-12-48-36-604: Failed. Reason: AlgorithmError: ExecuteUserScriptError:
Command "/bin/sh -c ./run_training.sh --model_dir /opt/training --num_train_steps 1000 --pipeline_config_path pipeline.config --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples 1"
```

Any help please?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4yEx.png

Comment: SageMaker unzips the files from the SM_MODULE_DIR. Does that zip file exist? s3://sagemaker-us-east-1-920101086824/tf2-licence-detection-2022-01-24-12-48-36-604/source/sourcedir.tar.gz